# How to speed up a linq statement that checks two lists for missing records

Tags: c#, linq

What I am trying to achieve.

I am working on a reconcile process and need to ensure my database table has the correct entries. I need to find records in a table that are not in a master list. When I have found these entries I need to group them and find the most recent in each group. If the operation fields of the most recent entries are defined as “Added”, I will need to add additional records with their operation fields marked as “Deleted”, as they are not defined in the master list.

The code I have written selects records in the database that are not in the master list. It then groups these and orders them and finally select the first item in each group which will now be the newest in each group. I then return only the items that have an operation defined as “Added”. I have run this code against my unit tests and with “real” data. Although it works, it is very slow taking maybe forty seconds when run against a database of 16 thousand records (when run from within visual studio). Can anyone advise on if it is possible to modify my code to improve the speed?

Shown below is the code that finds the mismatched records

```
        var linksInDb = _ctx.LinkRecords.ToList();

        return (from dbl in linksInDb select dbl)
            .Except(
                from dbl in linksInDb
                from l in links
                where dbl.EP1Id == l.Endpoints[0].EntityKey.EntityId && dbl.EP2Id == l.Endpoints[1].EntityKey.EntityId
                select dbl)
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.EP1Id, x.EP2Id},
                (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModifiedDate_UTC).First())
            .Where(x => x.Operation == "Added")
            .ToList();
```

NB. The master list called "links" is a generic list of type Link which is the same type returned by _ctx.LinkRecords.ToList();

Comment: You should specify what LINQ provider this is used against (EF? What version? Linq-To-SQL? Or something different altogether?), and you may want to inspect and post the SQL generated/executed.

Comment: Have you tried it without calling `ToList` on `_ctx.LinkRecords`? That will load all of the records from the database into memory, which may be what  is taking so long. By removing that, it will convert your query into SQL and run that in the database, which may end up being faster.

Comment: The second in memory query is far from optimal and for sure can be optimized. But before doing that, the question is how much time (from the total 15 sec) takes this statement `var linksInDb = _ctx.LinkRecords.ToList();`

Comment: The "LinkRecords.ToList" takes less than a second. The rest of the command takes 40 seconds when running this within visual studio.

Comment: Even if you are able to load all of the records quickly, you are now performing a complex operation on a large number of items. I would still recommend trying the query in the database first.